# How to store value in the CollectionView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I have a `CollectionView` list and want to set each item an individual value that when clicked it can get the value.

But it seems there is no such property how should to do?

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="5,5" HeightRequest="55">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.134*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.489*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.256*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer CommandParameter="{Binding Id}" Tapped="Handle_Tapped" />
                            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

I cannot get the param,pls help.

Comment: Maybe if you could show me what you have done so far I can give you a quick solution

Comment: @G.hakim please see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an item the event argument by default gets the selected data so you do not need an id to get that all you need to do is something like this :

```
 private void Handle_Tapped(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
     var clickedData=(e as ItemTappedEventArgs).Item as YourDataType;

    }
```

Where `YourDataType` is the `Type` bound to your CollectionView.

Comment: The sender is a Grid

Comment: That does not matter I am not casting the sender!

Comment: As your code ,there is an exception             Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: Can you tell me what type of Event Arguments do you get when you debug the click event

Comment: I find the right code myself when I see the code you give thank you.@G.hakim

Answer (score 1):

`CollectionView` offers a `SelectedItem` bindable property. You can bind to this property and perform whatever actions you need in your view model when it is set.

If you want to stick with an event, `CollectionView` also offers a `SelectionChanged` event that will fire every time the `SelectedItem` changes and it will pass the selected item each time as part of the arguments.

Either of these will remove the need to have a tap gesture recognizer for each view cell in the `CollectionView`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Grid h = sender as Grid;

        var m = h.BindingContext as YourModelType;

    }
```